# Salesforce Communities - Can I restrict the Global Search to a subset of accounts?

Tags: community

How do I restrict Global Search to only return active accounts? We have Customer Community licenses.

Comment: You can share only the active accounts with community users. How is your current sharing model working?

Comment: External Sharing Settings are set to Public Read Only because they want a Member Directory so all Community users should see all active Members. I also added a Sharing Set to allow only the logged-in user to edit their account and contact information. I have a field called 'Account Type' on the Account object that shows whether an Account is a member or not. I would like to be able to restrict Global Search so it only displays Accounts with Account Type=Member.

Comment: Unfortunately, Global search works in tandem with standard security model this means you probably need to build custom search.

Comment: Thanks. Not good news!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Global search works in tandem with standard security model this means you probably need to build custom search.